# python: как ускорить цикл for для более быстрого нажатия на экран по координатам

Tags: python, изображения

```
def ruin():
    #print('Цвета', color)
    print("старт")
    for x in range(im.size[1]):
        for y in range(im.size[0]):
            if imrgb.getpixel((y, x)) ==  (0, 0, 0):
                pyautogui.click(x+150, y+150, duration=0.001)
            if keyboard.is_pressed('esc') == True:
                sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хотя бы так (поменял местами итерации по `x`, `y`, чтобы выглядело "приятнее"):

```
def ruin():
    #print('Цвета', color)
    print("старт")
    keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', my_bind)
    for y in range(im.size[0]):
        for x in range(im.size[1]):
            if imrgb.getpixel((y, x)) ==  (0, 0, 0):
                pyautogui.click(x+150, y+150, duration=0.001)

    keyboard.remove_hotkey('esc')

def my_bind():
    keyboard.remove_hotkey('esc')
    sys.exit()
```